# What is the relation between the domain of Fractional Fourier transform and time and frequency?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum

This refers to Wikipedia's page on [Fractional Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Fourier_transform).
In the definition section it clearly writes that:

> The FrFT argument $u$ is neither a spatial one $x$ nor a frequency
> $\xi$. We will see why it can be interpreted as linear combination of
> both coordinates $(x,\xi)$

But I did not see the relation between the domain of Fractional Fourier transform ($u$) and space and frequency $(x,\xi)$. I can understand that domain '$u$' is a linear combination of '$(x,\xi)$' but my question what is the relation? Can anyone point out the exact relation?

Comment: up arrow on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It think it is more correct to say that the $u$ axis is a linear combination of the $x$ and $\xi$ axes:

$$(x, \xi) = (1, 0)x + (0, 1)\xi = \left((1, 0)\cos(\alpha) + (0, 1)\sin(\alpha)\right)u,$$

that is:

$$ x = u\cos(\alpha)\\
\xi = u\sin(\alpha).$$

The definition of the fractional Fourier transform from [that Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Fourier_transform) is:

> $$\mathcal{F}_\alpha[f](u) =  \sqrt{1-i\cot(\alpha)} e^{i \pi
> \cot(\alpha) u^2}  \int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{-i2\pi (\csc(\alpha) u x
> - \frac{\cot(\alpha)}{2} x^2)} f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x.$$

If you use another variable, $y$, for the integral, and substitute $u = \sqrt{x^2 + \xi^2}$ and $\alpha = \text{atan}(\xi, x)$, then the fractional Fourier transform can be written as:

$$\mathcal{F}[f](x, \xi) = e^{i \pi \frac{\xi}{x} (x^2+\xi^2)} \sqrt{1-\frac{i \xi}{x}}\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{i \pi \frac{y}{x} \left(\xi y-2 x^{\frac{1}{\xi}} \sqrt{\xi^2+x^2}\right)} f(y)\, \text{d}y.$$

Comment: Can we gain any insight by change of variable? I knew that relation to x but did not realize the relation to frequency.

Comment: Dunno, but it's the same as going from polar notation to rectangular notation.